# Backbone and dom issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, backbone.js

I've a view and into there is a listener on scroll. The problem is that scroll function get property from dom to calculate when load more model on page.The property from model getted are: scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight. The problem is that the value of this property never change even if you scroll the page. 
It seems so strange!I think scroll top must change when scroll down or up!

```
  var HomePostView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "ul",
   // id: "list",
   // el:$('.table-view'),
    template: Handlebars.compile(template),





    initialize: function () {
   //console.log(this.collection);
    // this.collection.bind("add", this.render, this);
    that = this;
     document.addEventListener("scroll", this.checkScroll, this);
     this.isLoading = false;
     this.IntegratedCollection= new Integrated();
     this.IntegratedCollection.twitterQuery=11265832;//spostare in load results
      this.IntegratedCollection.fetch();
     this.listenTo(this.IntegratedCollection,'add',this.render);

      console.log((this.el));

    },



    render:function(){

        this.loadResults();
    },






    loadResults: function (eventName) {

    this.isLoading = true;
      $(this.el).empty();
      _.each(this.IntegratedCollection.models, function (a) {
        $(this.el).append(new SingleHomePostView({
          model: a
        }).render().el);
      }, this);
      this.isLoading = false;
      return this;


    },

    setParameters: function(){

        this.IntegratedCollection.page += 1; // Load next page
      this.IntegratedCollection.twitterQuery=11265832;
      this.IntegratedCollection.fetch();




    },

     checkScroll: function () {

        console.log("scrollHeight"+that.el.scrollHeight);<--this value doesn't change
        console.log("scrollTop"+that.el.scrollTop);<--this value doesn't change
        console.log("clientHeight"+that.el.clientHeight);<--this value doesn't change
     // console.log(that.el.scrollTop + that.el.clientHeight + triggerPoint);
  var triggerPoint = 1; // 100px from the bottom

    if(that.el.scrollHeight - that.el.scrollTop === that.el.clientHeight ){console.log("finish spacescroll");};

    }



  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a scoping problem. inside of checkScroll, "that" is not defined. You defined "that" in initialize.
I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish with the "useCapture" parameter in addEventListener, but it will be coerced into a truthy value. Probably not what you're looking for.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', this.checkScroll, false);
// ...
checkScroll: function() {
  console.log('scrollHeight', this.el.scrollHeight);
  //...
}
```

Comment: I've changed as you told me with false but now checkScroll is never called.Why?

Comment: @user1938193 do you have a fiddle? Seems like something else is off.

Comment: I have not a fiddle. What do you mean for "something else is off"?

Comment: something else is the culprit here since document.addEventListener('scroll', function() { console.log('do something')}, false); will trigger "do something" while scrolling. It's straight forward, so I suspect something else is off.